# Javascript. Blackjack, hit function

Tags: javascript

I've been making a Blackjack game as a project for school, but I've been stuck at this certain point for a while now.

What I've succesfully done is generate 5 cards  with their corresponding pictures and numbers, but what I want to do is when I hit the button, it should only generate one card at a time.

Example if the user "hits" only 1 card should appear, if he hits again, the second card shall appear.

Here's my JS coding for showing the 5 cards

```
function StartGame()
{
    for (i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
    {
        for (j=1; j <= 52; j++)
        {
            if (RandomCards[i] == j)
            {
                if (Plade[i] == 0)
                {
                    if (i == 0)
                    {
                    Plade[i] = j
                    document.getElementById("img" + j).style.display = "block";
                    }
                    else if (i == 1)
                    {
                    Plade[i] = j
                    document.getElementById("img" + j).style.display = "block";
                    document.getElementById("img" + j).style.left = "455px";
                    }
                    else if (i == 2)
                    {
                    Plade[i] = j
                    document.getElementById("img" + j).style.display = "block";
                    document.getElementById("img" + j).style.left = "665px";
                    }
                    else if (i == 3)
                    {
                    Plade[i] = j
                    document.getElementById("img" + j).style.display = "block";
                    document.getElementById("img" + j).style.left = "875px";
                    }
                    else if (i == 4)
                    {
                    Plade[i] = j
                    document.getElementById("img" + j).style.display = "block";
                    document.getElementById("img" + j).style.left = "1085px";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (Plade[i] == 1)
        {
            DineKort[i] = 1
        }
        else if (Plade[i] == 2)
        {
            DineKort[i] = 2
        }
        else if (Plade[i] == 3)
        {
            DineKort[i] = 3
        }
        else if (Plade[i] == 4)
        {
            DineKort[i] = 4
        }
        else if (Plade[i] == 5)
        {
            DineKort[i] = 5
        }
        else if (Plade[i] == 6)
        {
            DineKort[i] = 6
        }
        else if (Plade[i] == 7)
        {
            DineKort[i] = 7
        }
        else if (Plade[i] == 8)
        {
            DineKort[i] = 8
        }
        else if (Plade[i] == 9)
        {
            DineKort[i] = 9
        }
        else if (Plade[i] == 10)
        {
            DineKort[i] = 10
        }
        else if (Plade[i] == 11)
        {
            DineKort[i] = 10
        }
        else if (Plade[i] == 12)
        {
            DineKort[i] = 10
        }
        else if (Plade[i] == 13)
        {
            DineKort[i] = 10
        }
        else if (Plade[i] == 14)
        {
            DineKort[i] = 1
        }
        else if (Plade[i] == 15)
        {
            DineKort[i] = 2
        }
        else if (Plade[i] == 16)
        {
            DineKort[i] = 3
        }
        else if (Plade[i] == 17)
        {
            DineKort[i] = 4
        }
        else if (Plade[i] == 18)
        {
            DineKort[i] = 5
        }
        else if (Plade[i] == 19)
        {
            DineKort[i] = 6
        }
        else if (Plade[i] == 20)
        {
            DineKort[i] = 7
        }
        else if (Plade[i] == 21)
        {
            DineKort[i] = 8
        }
        else if (Plade[i] == 22)
        {
            DineKort[i] = 9
        }
        else if (Plade[i] == 23)
        {
            DineKort[i] = 10
        }
        else if (Plade[i] == 24)
        {
            DineKort[i] = 10
        }
        else if (Plade[i] == 25)
        {
            DineKort[i] = 10
        }
        else if (Plade[i] == 26)
        {
            DineKort[i] = 10
        }
        else if (Plade[i] == 27)
        {
            DineKort[i] = 1
        }
        else if (Plade[i] == 28)
        {
            DineKort[i] = 2
        }
        else if (Plade[i] == 29)
        {
            DineKort[i] = 3
        }
        else if (Plade[i] == 30)
        {
            DineKort[i] = 4
        }
        else if (Plade[i] == 31)
        {
            DineKort[i] = 5
        }
        else if (Plade[i] == 32)
        {
            DineKort[i] = 6
        }
        else if (Plade[i] == 33)
        {
            DineKort[i] = 7
        }
        else if (Plade[i] == 34)
        {
            DineKort[i] = 8
        }
        else if (Plade[i] == 35)
        {
            DineKort[i] = 9
        }
        else if (Plade[i] == 36)
        {
            DineKort[i] = 10
        }
        else if (Plade[i] == 37)
        {
            DineKort[i] = 10
        }
        else if (Plade[i] == 38)
        {
            DineKort[i] = 10
        }
        else if (Plade[i] == 39)
        {
            DineKort[i] = 10
        }
        else if (Plade[i] == 40)
        {
            DineKort[i] = 1
        }
        else if (Plade[i] == 41)
        {
            DineKort[i] = 2
        }
        else if (Plade[i] == 42)
        {
            DineKort[i] = 3
        }
        else if (Plade[i] == 43)
        {
            DineKort[i] = 4
        }
        else if (Plade[i] == 44)
        {
            DineKort[i] = 5
        }
        else if (Plade[i] == 45)
        {
            DineKort[i] = 6
        }
        else if (Plade[i] == 46)
        {
            DineKort[i] = 7
        }
        else if (Plade[i] == 47)
        {
            DineKort[i] = 8
        }
        else if (Plade[i] == 48)
        {
            DineKort[i] = 9
        }
        else if (Plade[i] == 49)
        {
            DineKort[i] = 10
        }
        else if (Plade[i] == 50)
        {
            DineKort[i] = 10
        }
        else if (Plade[i] == 51)
        {
            DineKort[i] = 10
        }
        else if (Plade[i] == 52)
        {
            DineKort[i] = 10
        }
    }
    console.log(DineKort)
}
```

Comment: Before you go any further with your project, you should seriously reassess the whole approach with the use of 52+ conditions and research the use of arrays and methods such as `map()`. Use of events (`click`, `keypress`, etc) are essential to turn based games as well.

Comment: If you have created 5 cards from that code then please provide a [mcve] by clicking the `<>` button,. BTW, Blackjack begins with 2 cards for each player, so do you provide cards for 2 and a half players or one player for poker or go-fish?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see these messages. Thanks for your help though :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you defined your variables earlier and populated RandomCards, this should a more compact version of your code:

```
function StartGame()
{
    for (i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
    {
        document.getElementById("img" + RandomCards[i]).style.display = "block";
        if (i > 0)
        {
        document.getElementById("img" + RandomCards[i]).style.left = 245+210*i+"px";
        }
        DineKort[i] = Math.min(RandomCards[i]%13+1, 11)-1;
    }
    console.log(DineKort);
}
```

If you only want one card, rather than using a for cycle, just call the current position in the array.

```
var CurrCard=0;

function NextCard()
{
    if(CurrCard<5)
    {
        document.getElementById("img" + RandomCards[CurrCard]).style.display = "block";
        if (CurrCard > 0)
        {
        document.getElementById("img" + RandomCards[CurrCard]).style.left = 245+210*CurrCard+"px";
        }
        DineKort[CurrCard] = Math.min(RandomCards[CurrCard]%13+1, 11)-1;
    }
    console.log(DineKort[CurrCard]);
```